# Как изменять видимость пароля в IE7

Tags: javascript, html

Я делаю скрытие/открытие пароля по нажатию кнопки

Изменяю тип поля с помощью

```
document.getElementById('password').type = 'text'; // text/password
```

Но в IE7 это не работает.
Чем это можно заменить?

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, зачем вам IE7?

Comment: Без понятия, но заказчик просит

Comment: Заломите заказчику тройную цену за такие просьбы. Современные сайты даже в IE11 не работают (ВКонтакте недавно отказался, например), а поддержка IE7 это что-то вообще за гранью здравого смысла

Comment: Ну а вообще можно попробовать удалять старый input password и вместо него создавать новый input с нужным type, пихая его в то же место, где был удалённый элемент (но это мысли вслух, на практике не проверял, мне IE7 неинтересен)

Comment: Делал - толку 0

Comment: Может, у вас ваш код вообще не выполняется? Пробовали alert поставить?

Comment: Нет, сам код работает.

Comment: Проблему уже решил, правда с помощью большого костыля))